# «Review» button is disabled when creating Firebase A/B Testing Experiment

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I’m trying to create a new Remote Config experiment, but I get a warning «Install the latest version of the Remote Config SDK» even before selecting an app for use in a new experiment. I’m not sure if it is the reason but the button «Review» that I should click to create an experiment is disabled.
I've filled in all fields and got no warnings except "latest version" one.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This message is persistent in the console as a reminder for folks to install the newest SDK.  If you've got the most recent SDK version installed, then you're good to go.

Check the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android) for the latest version.

Comment: I do have latest version of firebase SDK, 15.0.2 in production, but I cannot create A/B experiment. Maybe "latest version" warning is not the reason, but I have no other warnings or errors, so I have no idea why the button "Review" is disabled

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fool. I did not fill in the "Goal" field ("Select goal metric"), but only set "Other metrics to track", so the button was disabled. It would be better if they make a standard red warning about this field not filled

Comment: You are not a fool, they should have a better validation user experience.
I have the same problem that the Next button is disabled and I just can't figure out why.